# winmerge : is it possible to execute a script on file1 before doing the compare between file1 and file2?

Tags: winmerge, cm-synergy

root cause of my asking :
because of our synergy configuration management tool we have a end of line conversion that is done automatically.
linux end of line (LF) are replaced by windows end of line (CRLF) each time we retrieve files from Synergy using a compare (no way to disable it in our synergy version 7.1)
The problem is that if the original file is CRLF then the conversion will be CRCRLF that is a wrong end of line. it is usally displayed with a parasit empty line.

all this to explain that doing a compare with winmerge from synergy is painfull because one compared file or both files have parasit empty lines.

I know that I can ask winmerge to ignore blank line during compare but these lines disturb winmerge doing correct compare when there are a lot of modifications. also reading files with blank line is painfull.
So I need to have a quick way in winmerge to execute a script on both file to replace all CRCRLF by CRLF.
the best would be to ask winmerge to activate the script all time when launching winmerge.exe

I see that in the GUI of winmerge there is a command "apply a script" but the list of script available can't be modified.